# Round down pandas datetime column to previous minute

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My dataframe looks like this:

```
      price                timestamp  amount  side
0  0.001728  2019-05-01 22:48:49.082    29.0   buy
1  0.001729  2019-05-01 21:26:22.078    31.0  sell
2  0.001730  2019-05-01 18:05:30.953    32.0   buy
3  0.001726  2019-05-01 18:05:40.412    32.0  sell
4  0.001730  2019-05-01 16:59:51.127    32.0  sell
5  0.001741  2019-05-01 12:23:19.957    32.0   buy
```

What I would like to have is the following:

```
      price           timestamp  amount  side
0  0.001728 2019-05-01 22:48:00    29.0   buy
1  0.001729 2019-05-01 21:26:00    31.0  sell
2  0.001730 2019-05-01 18:05:00    32.0   buy
3  0.001726 2019-05-01 18:05:00    32.0  sell
4  0.001730 2019-05-01 16:59:00    32.0  sell
5  0.001741 2019-05-01 12:23:00    32.0   buy
```

What I tried:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='%Y%m%d %H:%M')
```

But it did not change my dataframe... any idea why? thanks!

Comment: what's *minute based*?

Comment: @QuangHoang, you only have the minutes.. I added an example of what I am trying to achieve

Comment: cs95's answer is good, but I think it's also worth pointing out that you're using the wrong parameter to try and format your column. You should be using `format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'` instead of trying to pass the format to the `unit` parameter which is for changing the unit of your time measures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try flooring to the previous minute with `dt.floor`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], errors='coerce').dt.floor('min')

0   2019-05-01 22:48:00
1   2019-05-01 21:26:00
2   2019-05-01 18:05:00
3   2019-05-01 18:05:00
4   2019-05-01 16:59:00
5   2019-05-01 12:23:00
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

```
df.assign(
    timestamp=pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], errors='coerce').dt.floor('min'))

      price           timestamp  amount  side
0  0.001728 2019-05-01 22:48:00    29.0   buy
1  0.001729 2019-05-01 21:26:00    31.0  sell
2  0.001730 2019-05-01 18:05:00    32.0   buy
3  0.001726 2019-05-01 18:05:00    32.0  sell
4  0.001730 2019-05-01 16:59:00    32.0  sell
5  0.001741 2019-05-01 12:23:00    32.0   buy
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Numpy's `astype`

Because @cs95 was quicker with the answer I was going to give (-:

```
df.assign(timestamp=df.timestamp.astype('datetime64[m]'))

      price           timestamp  amount  side
0  0.001728 2019-05-01 22:48:00    29.0   buy
1  0.001729 2019-05-01 21:26:00    31.0  sell
2  0.001730 2019-05-01 18:05:00    32.0   buy
3  0.001726 2019-05-01 18:05:00    32.0  sell
4  0.001730 2019-05-01 16:59:00    32.0  sell
5  0.001741 2019-05-01 12:23:00    32.0   buy
```